# What can cause CloudWatch log lines to truncate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

When looking at logs, I often come across lines that are cut off, usually at the end of a process.

Example:

```
2024-01-19T14:33:30.496419+00:00 ip-10-1-35-200 runtime: test_clientId::qJXxa1fAapXTvW3yIvTZudtRuQk2odQHLHUJvvq5fBI=::[STDERR]: 
<13>Jan 19 14:33:30 runtime: test_clientId::qJXxa1fAapXTvW3yIvTZudtRuQk2odQHLHUJvvq5fBI=::[STDOUT]: 
[INFO] 2024-01-19 14:33:29.920 CurlHandleContainer [140243581757184] Connection has been released. Conti
```

The last word is truncated. How can this happen? I would think a string is all or nothing.

Comment: Are these API Gateway logs?

Comment: nope, just app logs